# What is the reason for the absence of articles in in "... with mien of lord or lady, perched above my chamber door" in "The Raven"?

Tags: articles, poetry

The seventh stanza of Edgar Allan Poe's *The Raven* reads as follows:

> Open here I flung the shutter, when, with many a flirt and flutter,
> In there stepped a stately Raven of the saintly days of yore;
> Not the least obeisance made he; not a minute stopped or stayed he;
> But, **with mien of lord or lady**, perched above my chamber door—
> Perched upon a bust of Pallas just above my chamber door—
> Perched, and sat, and nothing more.

In my opinion, *poetic license* is too general a term. To the best of my knowledge, certain grammatical quirks are permissible in English poetry so long as they conform with certain stable patterns, traditional deviations that do not clash with the music (for lack of a better term) of the language. The omission of two articles (a definite one and an indefinite one) in quick succession, within the same phrase, strikes me as somewhat unusual.

Are there precedents of this in English poetry?

Comment: Some fixed phrases have dropped or optionally dropped determiners. So,  'without risk to life and limb' / 'without recourse to pen(cil) and paper'. Poe wasn't bending the rules nearly as far as others have done.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Thank you.

Comment: Yes but I thought 'mien' meant something like 'appearance' or more likely 'manner'… which suggests that even in strict prose, Poe was more creative than mistaken and in poetry, there's no Question to Answer.